# PHP - remove divs and content inside

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, strip-tags

**HTML:**

```
<!--a lot of HTML before-->
<div class="quoteheader">
  <div class="topslice_quote"><a href="htsomelink">Some text</a></div>
</div>
<blockquote class="bbc_standard_quote">Some text<br />
</blockquote>
<div class="quotefooter">
  <div class="botslice_quote"></div>
</div>
<br />
<!--a lot of HTML after-->
```

**I NEED TO:** remove everything between div.quoteheader and first `<br/>` after, so result should looks like:

```
<!--a lot of HTML before-->
<!--a lot of HTML after-->
```

**I TRIED:**

```
$message = preg_replace('/<div\sclass=\"quoteheader\">[^<]+<\/div>/i', '', $string)
```

Comment: That would be everything between `div.quoteheader` and the *second* `<br />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) object with the HTML and then using [RemoveChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php).

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better served used an XML/HTML/DOM parser than regex. [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is pretty simple.

You would just load up the HTML w/ SimpleXML or some other HTML/XML parser, then use xpath to find the nodes and/or comments you're looking for, then remove them.

Comment: substr & strpos and strip_tags would be enough

Answer (score 0):

An alternative... if you can delimit the code with comments, like this:

```
<!--code-->
<div> .. </div>
<!--/code-->
```

you can remove everything between that:

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/<!--code-->.*?<!--\/code-->/is', '', $htmlstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(\<div\ class="quoteheader"\>)(.+)(<br \/>)/si', '', $string)
```